# Jquery JScrollPane - Set scroll speed/sensitivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane

I have a relatively simple question, I just can't find the solution for it anywhere.

Does anyone know, how to initialize the JScrollPane plugin ([plugin website](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)), with a bit more sensitive scroll speed? The default speed is just too slow and sluggish, especially on higher resolution monitors.

Example initialization:

```
 $('#element').jScrollPane();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for *wheelSpeed* (default is 18)

```
$('#element').jScrollPane({wheelSpeed: 50});
```

Answer (score 7):

try out this one to:

```
$('.ym-col3').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, mouseWheelSpeed: 60 });
```

the wheelspeed does not work at my page ..

Comment: Yes, this answer worked for me whereas the first answer (the accepted answer) did not.