# How to test the responsiveness of a scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari

It has been observed that certain JavaScript causes a scrolling list to move slowly in IE and Safari.  I have been asked to improve the performance.

(The JavaScript is a function on the hover of items in the list that is scrolled.  When the mousescroll is used to scroll, the movement is choppy and slow.)

Are there any ways to a make quantitative measurement of how fast the scroll bar is moving or how much movement I get from a given amount of scrolling?

I think it would be desirable to make hard measurements so I can determine if my optimizations are working.

Comment: While there isn't a fixed value, I've seen people say that anything that takes up to 0.2 seconds to be considered instantaneous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365877/jquery-jscrollpane-set-scroll-speed-sensitivity may this help you